# Target video source in HTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, video, src

My video is not playing after editing the source via JavaScript, can you help me with that?

```
HTML : <video class="background-video" controls muted loop autoplay>
       <source id="vid_tag" type="video/mp4"></video>

JS : document.querySelector('#vid_tag').src = "_1/video/bvid_1.mp4"
```

Comment: So it appears to work if i go to another page on the web and return to my liveserver view of the homepage... this is even more confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be an error with the path, maybe you wrote it wrong and the browser does not find it.

**Possible Solution:**

**(1) Fix HTML**: 
The ID should be written in the `<video>` tag's setup (not put in  `<source>` tag)

```
<video id="vid_tag" class="background-video" controls muted loop autoplay>
<source src="nothing.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

**(2) Fix JS:**

Replace  `document.querySelector('#vid_tag')` with something more direct like `document.getElementById("vid_tag")` where you access by the specific ID of the Element you want.

```
document.getElementById("vid_tag").src = "_1/video/bvid_1.mp4"; //# set new src
document.getElementById("vid_tag").load(); //# decode (process) the new file
```

Comment: Please don't put comments in an Answer box. I've updated with a possible solution so you get enough rep to allow comments.

Comment: this did it! additionally i had a mistake in the <script> tag by calling for type=“text/javascript“ which made it break. im so happy, thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

When you set the `src` attribute of a `<source>` element you need to call the `<video>`'s [`.load()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/load) for it to fetch the new value:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
  const url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Volcano_Lava_Sample.webm";
  document.querySelector("source").src = url;
  document.querySelector("video").load(); // required
}, { once: true });
```

```html
<video controls muted loop autoplay>
  <source id="vid_tag" type="video/webm">
</video>
<button>set source</button>
```

However, you'd be better not using the `<source>` at all anymore if you do set its `src` dynamically.
If you were using it for its ability to fallback when facing unsupported formats, then use the [`<video>.canPlayType()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canplaytype) method instead:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
  const url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Volcano_Lava_Sample.webm";
  const video = document.querySelector("video");
  if (video.canPlayType("video/webm")) {
    video.src = url;
  }
  else {
    // to-do: load an other source
    console.warn("format is not supported");
  }
}, { once: true });
```

```html
<video controls muted loop autoplay></video>
<button>set source</button>
```